# automatic resize with kendo UI

Tags: javascript, url, kendo-ui

I am trying to load the Remote content into the Kendo Ui popup with url. 
and i am able to load the content but popup window is not resizing according to the content. pls help me out on this. i am trying below code.

```
function openiframe(url) {
        if (url != '' && url != 'flowplayer') {
            var myWindow = $("#window");
            myWindow.kendoWindow({
                actions: ["Close"],
                width: '75%',
                height: '110%',
                position: {
                    top: '5%'
                   },
                modal: true,                   
                draggable: false,                    
                title: "Course window",
                resizable: true,
                content: url,
                close: SaveTime
              });
            $("#window").data("kendoWindow").center().open();

        }
```

Comment: Try to remove those parameters from your declaration: width: '75%',              height: '110%'. By default, Kendo UI Window does not have any preset dimensions and its size depends on its content.

Comment: i have tried but it's not working as expected with content

Comment: Try to set it's height and it's width to *auto*.